# Flow: computed property. Indexable signature not found in... when type is class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

How to fix an error in this case (keeping using class as type):

```
/* @flow */

class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const person: Person = new Person();
person.name = 'Bob';
person.age = 25;

['name', 'age'].forEach(key => {
  if(person[key]) {
    console.log(person[key]);
  }
});
```

The error points to `person[key]` and says:

> Cannot get `person[key]` because an indexer property is missing in
>   `Person`

In similar situation (may be different flow version) it says:

> computed property. Indexable signature not found in `Person`

Comment: looks like it's [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1323)

Answer (score 1):

I think the bigger issue is that `Array.prototype.forEach` has the type

```
forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: $ReadOnlyArray<T>) => any, thisArg?: any): void;
```

https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/3baafb0f2191353cd896d6fe087aea535bc8606e/lib/core.js#L211.

You can see that the `value` parameter has type `T`, which is determined by the type of the elements in the array. In your case, Flow is (most likely) assuming the type of the array `['name', 'age']` to be `string[]`. Thus, the type `T` is set to `string`.

Now, when you try to access `person[key]`, Flow will complain that you are missing an indexer property. This is accurate since you are trying to use a generic `string` access on the `Person` instance. This problem persists even after removing the conditional, which hints that Flow is unable to refine the `string` type to be one of `'name'` and `'age'`.

It would be nice if Flow could refine something like this

```
/* @flow */

class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const person: Person = new Person();
person.name = 'Bob';
person.age = 25;

['name', 'age'].forEach(key => {
  if (key === 'name') {
    console.log(person[key]);
  }
});
```

not necessarily because it's useful but because it is so explicit and should be a safe access at that point.

I would try to avoid using a loop through a list of properties to get/set properties on an object since Flow doesn't deal with the nuances of arrays that act like tuples yet. Plus, it's more future-proof to loop through the object itself (e.g., `Object.keys`) in case the object's properties ever get changed.